# Nested block is redundant warning ESLint

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have a warning that nested block is redundant, no-lone-blocks.

```
      {
         products.forEach((product) => {
            this.props.currentUserTags.forEach((tag) => {
               if (tag.id === product.tag.id) {
                  recommendations.push(product);
               }
            });
         });
      }
```

I am unsure of what I can change about this syntax when it comes to this warning?

Comment: Just remove the outer curly braces

Answer (score 0):

The rule mentions `This rule aims to eliminate unnecessary and potentially confusing blocks at the top level of a script or within other blocks.`

[no-lone-blocks](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-lone-blocks)

From the code snippet you mentioned you've the outer curly braces which are unnecessary so eliminating it fixes the warning/error.

```
 products.forEach((product) => {
    this.props.currentUserTags.forEach((tag) => {
       if (tag.id === product.tag.id) {
          recommendations.push(product);
       }
    });
 });
```